# How to use pyserial to write two separate message?

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, python

I'm using pyserial to communicate with my arduino. I set up the connection and everything works fine. Now I have these two writing commands:

```python
pyserial.write("conn".encode())
pyserial.write("mod1".encode())
```

On my arduino:

```cpp
while (!Serial.available());
String s = Serial.readString();
if (s=="conn") do...;
if (s=="mod1") do...;
```

The problem is that none of the `if` statements are true because `s` becomes `"connmod1"`, because the messages are sent almost at the same time I guess. I know I could use some delimiter to split the string, but I would like to know what the convenient solution might be?

Comment: you already answered your own question `I know i could use some delimiter`

Comment: readString() waits for the next character until timeout. default timeout is 1 second. you can set the timeout with Serial.setTimeout(millis). https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readstring/

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick, cheap, and easy solution, you could just use `sleep()` in your Python script to put a delay between the commands. This obviously isn't a perfect solution, but it's not difficult to implement.

Or, like you said, you could use a delimiter. It's not as easy to implement, but it'll work better.

If you go the delimiter rout, you'll probably need to use `Serial.read()` instead of `Serial.readString()`. That way you can examine characters individually as they come in. You can store your characters in a String or char array until you detect your delimiter and then execute your command.

Hope that helps!